# React: Cant call setState on a component that is not yet mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm creating a simple todo app using react(MERN stack). The above warning appears when I try to call a get API with axios and setState at the same time. I've gone through other threads on stack overflow with the same problem but none of them were really that useful. I've even tried messing around with a "isMounted" variable. Below is my code...

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  _isMounted = false;

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {list:[], itemCounter: 0};
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.handleDone = this.handleDone.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this._isMounted = true;

    axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/todo/api/`)
      .then(res => {
        if(this._isMounted){
          const list = res.data;
          const unDoneList = list.filter(task => task.done === false)
          this.setState({ list: list, itemCounter: unDoneList.length });
      }});
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  addItem(val) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/todo/api/task/', { data: val })
    .then(res => {
      const itemCounter = this.state.counter + 1;
      const updatedList = this.state.list;
      updatedList.push({ data: val, done: false });
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data);
      this.setState({ list: updatedList, itemCounter: itemCounter });
    })
  }
  
  handleDone(item){
    console.log(item._id)
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/todo/api/delete/${item._id}`)
    .then(() => console.log("Item Deleted."));

    let updatedList = this.state.list;
    updatedList.forEach(task => {
      if(task.id === item.id ){
        task.done = true;
      }
    });    
    const itemCounter = this.state.itemCounter - 1;
    this.setState({ list: updatedList, itemCounter: itemCounter });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <nav className="panel is-primary light">
        <Title itemCount={this.state.itemCounter}></Title>
        <Add addItem={this.addItem}></Add>
        <Items items={this.state.list} handleDone={this.handleDone}></Items>
      </nav>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For reference, I've uploaded my entire project on GitHub: https://github.com/mohnishm/Todo-App-in-React
How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `componentDidMount` lifecycle method inside your constructor, you should not do that.

Here is the problem:

```
this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount(this);
```

If you do that inside the `constructor` you would get that warning, React is telling you that the component is not yet mounted but you have already called `setState` through the manual call to the `componentDidMount`.

In your case the constructor has not finished executing and the component didn't get a chance to get mounted on to the DOM. Once the constructor is executed, the component is initialized and then the component is actually mounted on to the DOM.

With the component mounted, your lifecycle method `componentDidMount` would be invoked by React with the proper context (so there is no need to call `bind` on `componentDidMount`) and then at that point of time you should call `setState` to alter the state of the component.

Also you can remove the `_isMounted` and the checks related to that property form `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` as it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

componentDidMount is a lifecycle methods and doesnt require initilization inside the constructor. Remove it to avoid the warning.

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {list:[], itemCounter: 0};
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.handleDone = this.handleDone.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount(this); // remove this, componentDidMount is a lifecycle method.
  }
```

Comment: @Fullstack guy has already provided the solution. Thanks a lot anyway!